# SQL error 1215(HY000) cannot add foreign key constraint.

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

I looked through other questions on this topic, and the general consensus was to check my data type consistency. I am trying to create the table 'reviews' that has SSN and ProjectID as foreign keys,  referencing SSN from Table Reviewer and ProjectID from Table Project

```
CREATE TABLE Reviews(

ProjectID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

SSN INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK

    (SSN>100000000 AND SSN<999999999),

ReviewerRole VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

FOREIGN KEY(SSN)REFERENCES Reviewer(SSN),

FOREIGN KEY(ProjectID)REFERENCES Project(ProjectID),

PRIMARY KEY(SSN,ProjectID)
);
```

The following are the create table statements for 'Project' and 'Reviewer'

```
CREATE TABLE Reviewer(
SSN INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (SSN>100000000 AND SSN<999999999),
Firstname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Lastname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE Project(
ProjectID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Title VARCHAR(50),
Archived DATE NOT NULL,
ProjectStatus VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(ProjectID)
);
```

Project and Reviewer created without issue. My create Reviews query works if I remove the FK declaration for SSN and leave the FK declaration for ProjectID, but not the other way around.

What is the reason for the error? Is there another constraint I need to add?

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to add a primary key to the SSN column in the Reviewer table. The query below builds correctly in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b6f8ac):

```
CREATE TABLE Reviewer(
SSN INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (SSN>100000000 AND SSN<999999999),
Firstname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Lastname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(SSN)
);
CREATE TABLE Project(
ProjectID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
Title VARCHAR(50),
Archived DATE NOT NULL,
ProjectStatus VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(ProjectID)
);
CREATE TABLE Reviews(

ProjectID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

SSN INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK

    (SSN>100000000 AND SSN<999999999),

ReviewerRole VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,

FOREIGN KEY(SSN)REFERENCES Reviewer(SSN),

FOREIGN KEY(ProjectID)REFERENCES Project(ProjectID),

PRIMARY KEY(SSN,ProjectID)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

A foreign key can only reference to a Primary Key column in another table, you need to make SNN a primary key column.

```
CREATE TABLE Reviewer(
SSN INTEGER NOT NULL primary key CHECK (SSN>100000000 AND SSN<999999999),
Firstname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Lastname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed this, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `referenced` column for a `foreign key` column, needs to be `Primary key` **OR** have a `unique constraint` so your `Reviewer` table need to be:

```
CREATE TABLE Reviewer(
SSN INTEGER PRIMARY KEY CHECK (SSN>100000000 AND SSN<999999999),
Firstname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Lastname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

**or**

```
CREATE TABLE Reviewer(
SSN INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (SSN>100000000 AND SSN<999999999),
Firstname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
Lastname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
UNIQUE(SSN)
);
```

Also as far as I know, MySQL Ignores `Check` Constraints, so you can remove them.